# Select items from a listbox through a loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I want to make it so that through a loop, it will select an item from the listbox. I was thinking about doing a for loop. This is (basically) what I want to accomplish:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbRooms.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lbRooms.Items.Select(i);
    // do stuff here with the selected item
}
```

I know thats not how it works, but I want it to do it like that. I appreciate all the help, thanks =D

EDIT: I think this will work, but I'm sure it can be improved:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbRooms.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lbRooms.SetSelected(i, true);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to select every single item in the listbox and do something to that item? Do you simply want a random item from the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lbRooms.setSelected(i, true);
```

instead of:

```
lbRooms.Items.Select(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (listitem item in lbRooms.Items)
    //do item manipulation here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select your items like that, You can use indexer to get your item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbRooms.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var currentItem = lbRooms.Items[i];
}
```

If you want to select that item you can set Selected property to true:

```
currentItem.Selected = true;
```